# Are the privacy features of Firefox 69.0 complementary to PrivacyBadger 2019.7.1.1?

Tags: firefox

Are the [privacy features](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/features/adblocker/) (blocking of Trackers, Cookies, Cryptominers, Fingerprinters) of Firefox 69.0 complemantary to PrivacyBadger? or do they interfere with each other?

Comment: The last release of PrivacyBadger was 2 months ago (before the release of Firefox 69.0). According firefox's new ETP, with miners added, the only thing i dubt is about browser fingerprinting but if the settings are set to 'normal mode' it shouldn't be a problem since these protections do only apply for strict mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox' new Enhanced Tracking Protection (ETP) does in fact the same what PrivacyBadger does, It blacklists Cross-Site trackers, blacklists cryptominers (although I'm not aware of one), so **there is no need to use PrivacyBadger longer**. Furthermore you can disable or allow third-party cookies. If you want to use PrivacyBadger anyway then I recommend Browserprivacy set to 'normal mode' otherwise there is a possibility whereby PrivacyBadger features can conflict with Firefox' new features since these protections only apply with Browserprivacy [set](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/69.0/releasenotes/) to strict-mode. Privacy Badger does protect you against canvas-based fingerprinting, Firefox does this also and thus there is a possibility that both can conflict with each other. [1](https://www.theverge.com/2019/4/9/18301835/firefox-anti-tracking-fingerprinting-crytocurrency-mining-cryptojacking)

*Two security-guards that do the same is worthless and likely will override the existing security.*